# There are no packages ready for upgrade, Mavensmate

Tags: sublimetext3

I've tried following the example to upgrade my MavensMate to the beta version 7.  I've added "MavensMate" to the in_process_packages in the package control user settings and then running the upgrade packages but get a message There are no packages ready for upgrade.  I've tried uninstalling Mavensmate and then re-installing with Mavensmate in the in_process_packages.  Still just installs v6.  I do have the mavensmate app installed and running (I think).

-edit- 
I've tried removing "MavensMate" from installed Packages in the package control user settings.  Then using the command line to remove Mavensmate.  Then I go back into sublime and add "MavensMate" to the in_process_packages.  Go to package control --> Install packages --> mavensmate.  It just installs v6.   I do have the latest version of the mavensmate app installed also.

If after v6 is installed and I try adding MavensMate to in_process and try package control --> Install Packages --> MavensMate is not listed.  If I try Upgrade instead of Install it says nothing to upgrade.

I do have the mavensmate.app installed and setup the workspace.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong when trying to get v7 installed.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured out what I was doing wrong. So if it helps anyone else. I was putting "MavensMate" in "in_process_packages":[] and not "install_prereleases":[] Once I put it in the correct place and then went to pack control: install Packages and installed mavensmate it worked.  So if you're experiencing the same issue check your package control user setting.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to see "MavensMate Upgrade" option in package control. After multiple trying I found some stupid typo. If it doesn't work and this is the issue, I would recommend copying the parameters:

```js
"installed_prereleases":
 [
  "MavensMate"
 ],
```

to

```js
"install_prereleases":
 [
  "MavensMate"
 ],
```

Comment: Definitely that was a stupid mistake, but it took pretty good chunk of my time.